# Unable to --reload on docker Fast API

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I have a problem with reloading my code after changes. I had to restart container manually to see updates on code. Here is my docker-compose code.

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
    - SECRET_KEY = ${SECRET_KEY}
    - ALGORITHM = ${ALGORITHM}
    - ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = ${ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES}
    volumes:
       - ./backend/:/app/backend
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres -d my_db"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 60
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

And here is my directory structur
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hr6C.png)

Comment: If your host is a Windows host with WSL2, it might be because there's an issue with inotify events not being sent to the container.

Comment: Try ` --reload` just after `main:app`

Answer (score 1):

So most likely you must have it say

```
command: bash -c "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload"
```

otherwise Uvicorn may not be loading Watchfiles dependancy correctly.

> If Uvicorn cannot load watchfiles at runtime, it will periodically look for changes in modification

> For more nuanced control over which file modifications trigger reloads, install uvicorn[standard], which includes watchfiles as a dependency. Alternatively, install watchfiles where Uvicorn can see it.

https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/ for more extensive documentation